# Using the Razor engine to set specific css classes based on the current view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've just started using the Razor engine with MVC3, so apologies if this is a pretty simple question.

I'm rendering my navigation bar using a `@Html.Partial('_SideBarPartial')` call, what I need is the `_SideBarPartial.cshtml` to set a css class on a specific node, if that node contains in it's children the current view.

Currently `_SideBarPartial.cshtml` is just a static html file, with a `<ul><li></li>..</ul>` setup.

Any pointers on what/how to go about this would be appreciated.

Thanks, Psytronic

Comment: You can pass data using the model parameter to the partial. What have you tried so far?

@Html.Partial('_SideBarPartial', somedata)

Comment: @Ed Charbeneau, not tried anything yet as not sure on the best way to go about it, was looking for more hints on what to use, rather than a straight out answer. So you're suggesting that I add maybe an enum (representing possible nav nodes) to the master model, and set that on each view, and then check that property when rendering out the nav bar and assign class as appropriate?

Comment: I think this article would be of some help to you.
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/105/ASP.NET-MVC-Partial-Views-and-Strongly-Typed-Custom-ViewModels

Answer (score 0):

I would use @Html.Partial('_SideBarPartial', `somedata`)

Where `somedata` is a **view model** containing the information needed to build the elements and set the CSS on the necessary element node(s).